# How to find the direction of the magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields

When I was reading the chapter of magnetic field I got to know about the direction of the magnetic field around current carrying various shapes but I was confuse there as in some cases the direction of magnetic field was found using Right Hand Thumb Rule whereas in some it was found using cross product formula isn't there a single method to find the direction of magnetic field applicable for all.  Need fast help.

Comment: use a compass...

Comment: It's basic that the right hand rule is a way to know the direction of the result of the cross product. You should do a little research of cross product before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand thumb rule:

"Thumb points along vector current, then the magnetic field wraps in the direction of your fingers"

*is* the right-hand rule for cross-products. In that formulation:

"move fingers from current to position vector, thumb aligns with magnetic field",

or:

$$ \vec J \times \vec r \rightarrow \vec B $$

Comment: Can't we use the single rule which says that thumb points in the direction of current and fingers in direction of magnetic field for all cases

Comment: Can you please give a 3D diagram